# vb.net - change behaviour of tab keydown (If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then...) inside richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, formatting, richtextbox

When pressing TAB inside a richtextbox I want the enitre line to be centered.

I have 2 questions :

1. I can't seem to be able to suppress what tab normally does.
   I have tried

   ```
       Private Sub rtbScript_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles rtbScript.KeyDown
       If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then
       e.SuppressKeyPress = True
       MsgBox("tab key pressed")
       End If
       End Sub
   ```

the result is still a tabulation in the richtextbox

2. how to center the exact line in the richtextbox where the tab key was pressed
   I have no code for this yet

any and all ideas would be much appreciated!
thx!

Comment: The tab key is used for navigation, moving the focus from one control to another, so your KeyDown event never fires.  Add an event handler for PreviewKeyDown, write If e.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then e.IsInputKey = True and now KeyDown fires as you want.  Do think a bit about how the user of your program is going to discover that tab does something useful, given how unusual it is.  Ctrl+E is a common choice, made discoverable with an annotation on a menu item.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.   that did not seem to have worked.  the tabulation still occured.  any other ideas that I could try? thx!

Comment: If it didn't work then you probably did it wrong. If you update your question and show us what you did then we may be able to determine what's wrong with it.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney : I already deleted the code, but  I got it to work with rtbScript.SelectionTabs = New Integer() {(rtbScript.Width / 2)} - so I'm quite happy with it.  thanks to everyone for taking an interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it!

```
rtbScript.SelectionTabs = New Integer() {(rtbScript.Width / 2)}
```

this seems to do the trick!  thanks for your time everyone!